# How can I test the page title while working with Sinatra + MiniTest

Tags: ruby, sinatra, minitest

I am having the configuration as below :

***Rakefile***

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.pattern = 'spec/*_spec.rb'
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'thin'
gem 'rack-test'
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'rack/test'
require_relative '../app'

include Rack::Test::Methods

def app
  MyApp
end
```

**app_spec.rb**

```
require_relative 'spec_helper'

describe 'Hello World' do

  it 'should have hello world' do
    get '/'
    last_response.must_be :ok?
    # I want to do something like below
    last_response.title must_match /home page/i
  end
end
```

How can I test the page title of a view using MiniTest and Sinatra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check this with `minitest` alone.

You should be looking at **[Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-minitestspec)** to achieve this.

> Capybara helps you test web applications by simulating how a real user
>   would interact with your app.

Once setup use **[has_title?](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Simple#has_title?-instance_method)** matcher to test the title of the rendered page.

Using Capybara you can test various aspects of your page like its content/text, if it has a particular link or not, a particular button, text field, email field, etc. 
You can simulate the behavior of filling up a form and clicking on a button to submit the same. Putting it simply, it just behaves as a real user would by simulating the actions that a user can perform on a given page with what all a user can see on a given page.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Could you accept the answer to solve this question?